# Boostrap 4: Make textarea match column height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a textarea inside a bootstrap column fill the remaining height of the column with CCS (no JS).

```css
.form-row {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.col-9 {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.col-3 {
  background: violet;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Your Text</label>
      <textarea class="form-control">This textarea should fill the remaining height / green box</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

The textarea on the left side should match the height of the right side (fill the remaining height of the parent).

However I am not entirely sure how to achieve this in a simple way - without modifying every col/form-group.
Making the textarea `height: 100%` is not a solution, since it will overflow the parent.

[Fiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/3bkfjsqu/1/)

Update: It should also keep the `margin-bottom` of the form-group inside the column. Final result should look something like [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L84t6pox/)

```css
.form-row {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.col-9 {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.col-3 {
  background: violet;
}

textarea.form-control {
  height: 96px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Your Text</label>
      <textarea class="form-control">This textarea should fill the remaining height / green box</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br> some random stuff<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
HTML

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="form-group form-div">
      <label>Your Text</label>
      <textarea class="form-control">This textarea should fill the remaining height / green box</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    some random stuff<br>
    some random stuff<br>
    some random stuff<br>
    some random stuff<br>
    some random stuff<br>
    some random stuff<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-row {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.col-9 {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.col-3 {
  background: violet;
}

.form-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

textarea.form-control {
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can read about flex properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a good solution. However I'd like to keep the `margin` of the `form-group` inside the green box.

Comment: To achieve this you can give `margin-bottom: 1rem` to `textarea`. Or instead of `margin-bottom` you can give `padding-bottom`